# Importrange, but don't include if a date and only select a certain country

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, importrange

Hope someone can help

I've imported the range of a google spreadsheet however I need it to only pick up from a list of EU countries & also if a date is in a certain box not to pick it up at all. the picture should make it more clear.

[image: Capture]

I've tried:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/… Master!A5:AZ"), "Select Col4 where Col6 matches '"&JOIN("|", 'EU Countries'!$A1:$A28)&"' and not Col1 matches '"&JOIN("|", $A2:$A)
```

I've added another TAB listing the EU Countries

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: =QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NjjkYdv41pNTn71EppN_psYQ6Ex2ntJobtPZLxGqVrg/edit#gid=0","SVR Master!A5:AZ"),
"Select Col4 where Col6 matches '"&JOIN("|", 'EU Countries'!$A1:$A28)&"' and not Col1 matches '"&JOIN("|", $A2:$A)        I've added another TAB listing the EU Countries